# NSFetchResultsController iOS4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm only getting this error in my app since upgrading to ios4.

```
newsDetailController.news = (News *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"\n Indexpath of details news before pass = %@", [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:newsDetailController.news]);
```

Basically, this:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:newsDetailController.news])
```

returns `NULL`.

Why would this be?

`newsDetailController.news` isn't `NULL`.

### Edit:

To highlight this:

```
NSLog(@"\n Indexpath of detailssss news before pass = %@", [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]);
```

... returns NULL, even though:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

...returns an object.

Comment: To highlight this:

 NSLog(@"\n Indexpath of detailssss news before pass = %@", [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]]);

returns NULL, even though:

[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] returns an object.

Comment: As an aside, the cast you perform in `newsDetailController.news = (News *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` is completely unnecessary.  `-objectAtIndexPath:` returns an `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you positive that the news property (I am guessing it is a property on your detail view controller) is not `nil`?  Are you confirming your assumptions that both `newsDetailController` and `newsDetailController.news` are not `nil`?

iOS4 has brought with it proper non-fragile iVars.  If you were doing something incorrect in your @property declarations before that "worked" then the changes to iOS4 may now be catching that mistake.

Step one, walk the code in the debugger and make sure everything has a value that you expect to have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when something goes wonky with the indexes of a fetched results controller, it's because a mistake as been made with the section info e.g. adding a section key when you don't have sections. You should also not use the cache until you resolve the problem.

In this case, you also want to make sure that `news` is an object that represents a complete entity. If you use a keypath as the object to return at the indexpath, it has to be an object at the other end of a relationship, it can't be an object (such as an `NSString`) that holds the data of an attribute.

If `news` is a relationship, the FRC walks the object graph and returns the indexPath. However, if `news` is just an attribute, then it has no indexPath because indexPaths only describe the route to an entity in the object graph.